# How to get the text from the group of XML nodes using Java?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Following is the XML file -

```
<Country>
  <Group>
    <C>Tokyo</C>
    <C>Beijing</C>
    <C>Bangkok</C>
  </Group>
  <Group>
    <C>New Delhi</C>
    <C>Mumbai</C>
  </Group>
  <Group>
    <C>Colombo</C>
  </Group>
</Country>
```

I want to save the name of Cities to a text file using Java & XPath - 
Below is the Java code which is unable to do the needful.

```
.....
.....
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse("Continent.xml");
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
// XPath Query for showing all nodes value
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//Country/Group");
Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Cities.txt"));
Node node;
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) 
{
    node = nodes.item(i);
    String city = xpath.evaluate("C",node);
    out.write(" " + city + "\r\n");
}
out.close();
.....
.....
```

Can somebody help me to get the required output?

Comment: So your question is how to write the city to file?

Comment: @Rudy - Yes... only CITIES...

Comment: When you said unable, which line does throw you the error?

Comment: @Rudy- NO ERROR... but I am getting only FIRST City name out of the total 3 `Group`. Where as I want all the Cities. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting only the first city because that's what you asked for. Your first XPATH expression returns all the `Group` nodes. You iterate over these and evaluate the XPATH `C` relative to each `Group`, returning a single city.

Just change the first XPATH to `//Country/Group/C` and eliminate the second XPATH altogether -- just print the text value of each node returned by the first XPATH.

I.e.:

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//Country/Group/C");
...
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) 
{
    node = nodes.item(i);
    out.write(" " + node.getTextContent() + "\n");
}
```

Comment: what changes to do? I didnt get the exact required output..!!

Comment: the code worked very well and output was as required.. Thanks a lot